# how to use date(), timezone() and timestamp() command in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, date, timezone, timestamp

Good day. may i ask how the timestamp() and timezone() command is working? i tried to put a date (8-13-1996),  but the date that inserted in the database is (1970-01-01). is it the timestamp() or the timezone() command?
here is my code..

```
$bday = $this->input->post('mm')+" "+$this->input->post('dd')+" "+$this->input->post('yy');
$new_member_insert_data = array(

    'birthday' =>date("Y-m-d", strtotime($bday))

);
$insert = $this->db->insert('users', $new_member_insert_data);
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems `strtotime` cannot convert the string into time.It gets false.

```
date("Y-m-d",false)==1970-01-01
date("Y-m-d",0)==1970-01-01
```

you should better check if it can covert the string into time

```
 $bday = $this->input->post('mm')+" "+$this->input->post('dd')+" "+$this->input->post('yy');
 $time=strtotime($bday);
 if($time!==false)//insert it if $bday can convert into time
 {
   $new_member_insert_data = array(

     'birthday' =>date("Y-m-d", $time)

   );
   $insert = $this->db->insert('users', $new_member_insert_data);
}
```

Also you converting the string wrong way.You used `+`it should be `.`
Use this way  `$bday=$this->input->post('mm')."-".$this->input->post('dd')."-".$this->input->post('yy');`